# Wireless adapter not working after 12.10 install

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my dell pc and now my wireless adapter will not work at all?

The wireless adapter is a Belkin N1 Wireless Adapter, is there a way to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: I have a question, did you upgrade your Dell Pc from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10?